# How to split a dataframe after matching with another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes. Say `df_1`, and `df_2`. First, I am matching the rows between these 2 dataframes. After founding some matches, I want to divide the `df_1` into two new datframe. One will contains all information + 50% match information and the second will contain the rest of the 50% match information. For example,

df_1

```
  query target new_ssp
1  ID_1   ID_2    0.50
2  ID_3   ID_2    0.90
3  ID_3   ID_4    0.80
4 ID_40  ID_50    0.70
5 ID_15  ID_31    0.50
6  ID_1   ID_6    0.09
```

df_2

```
  query target  ssp
1  ID_1   ID_2 0.50
2  ID_2   ID_3 0.90
3  ID_3   ID_4 0.80
4  ID_4   ID_5 0.70
5  ID_5   ID_3 0.50
6  ID_6   ID_1 0.09
```

The match (`common`) between them using `common <- inner_join(df_1, df_2)`

```
  query target new_ssp ssp
1  ID_1   ID_2     0.5 0.5
2  ID_3   ID_4     0.8 0.8
```

I want to make another df_3 (removed 50% matched data with `df_1` and `common`). Removed row number 3 of the `df_1`.

```
  query target new_ssp
1  ID_1   ID_2    0.50
2  ID_3   ID_2    0.90
3 ID_40  ID_50    0.70
4 ID_15  ID_31    0.50
5  ID_1   ID_6    0.09
```

And `df_4` (rest of the matched after removing in terms of `df_1` and `common`). Removed row number 2 of the `common`.

```
  query target new_ssp ssp
1  ID_1   ID_2     0.5 0.5
```

How can I do make this two new dataframe?

Reproducible data

```
query <- c("ID_1", "ID_3", "ID_3", "ID_40", "ID_15", "ID_1")
target <- c("ID_2", "ID_2", "ID_4", "ID_50", "ID_31", "ID_6")
new_ssp <- c(0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.09)
df_1 <- data.frame(query, target, new_ssp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

query <- c("ID_1", "ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_6")
target <- c("ID_2", "ID_3", "ID_4", "ID_5", "ID_3", "ID_1")
ssp <- c(0.5, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.09)
df_2 <- data.frame(query, target, ssp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: You want to create `df_4` alone?

Comment: no `df_3` and `df_4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
df_4 <- slice_head(common,  prop = 0.5)

df_3 <- anti_join(df_1,  anti_join(common, df_4))
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
common <- cbind(merge(df_1, df_2), grp = 1:2)
dflst <- list(df_1, df_2)
lapply(
  seq_along(dflst),
  function(k) {
    subset(
      merge(dflst[[k]], common, all.x = TRUE),
      is.na(grp) | grp != k
    )[names(dflst[[k]])]
  }
)
```

gives

```
[[1]]
  query target new_ssp
2  ID_1   ID_6    0.09
3 ID_15  ID_31    0.50
4  ID_3   ID_2    0.90
5  ID_3   ID_4    0.80
6 ID_40  ID_50    0.70

[[2]]
  query target  ssp
1  ID_1   ID_2 0.50
2  ID_2   ID_3 0.90
4  ID_4   ID_5 0.70
5  ID_5   ID_3 0.50
6  ID_6   ID_1 0.09
```

Comment: Thank you very much